# Creating clusters with same number of points in each in CartoDB

Tags: carto, clustering

I have a map of about 4200 retailers and I would like to create clusters, with each cluster containing 10 retailers in CartoDB. How can I do this?

Comment: Clustering is generally based on proximity, not number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

As John says, the clusters are created automatically by taking into account the spatial location of the points.

You can see an example of a clustering query [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8306637):

```
WITH hgridA AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48) as cell),
    bigs AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridA, (select * from tornados_copy) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridA.cell) GROUP BY hgridA.cell) t WHERE points_count > 100 ),
    hgridB AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36) as cell),
    mids AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridB, (select * from tornados_copy) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridB.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) GROUP BY hgridB.cell) t WHERE points_count > 25 ),
    hgridC AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24) as cell),
    smalls AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridC, (select * from tornados_copy) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridC.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM mids) GROUP BY hgridC.cell) t WHERE points_count > 5 )
    SELECT the_geom_webmercator, 1 points_count, cartodb_id, ARRAY[cartodb_id], 'origin' as src FROM tornados_copy WHERE cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM mids) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM smalls)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'bigs' as src FROM bigs
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *, 'mids' as src FROM mids
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *, 'smalls' as src FROM smalls
```

[This other example](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8675947) uses a similar code but allows the user to select the grid size that defines the clustering region.